# How do banks handle cross bank transaction?

Tags: cross-platform, atomic, banking

let's just say that customer A in bank 1 wants to send 1000$ money to customer B in bank 2.
How do the banks make sure that this transaction is atomic?

I understand that inside the same database, we can use database transaction to ensure the atomicity.
But how is that accomplished if it's cross applications?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the banking transactions work "under the hood" - possibly in detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512547/how-does-the-banking-transactions-work-under-the-hood-possibly-in-detail)

Comment: they don't they settle the difference only at the end if day or whenever is convenient